# Ошибки при компиляции(opengl32.lib glu32.lib)

Tags: c++, opengl

> Ошибка    1   error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "opengl32.lib"   C:\Users\Виктор\Desktop\OPENGL_PRIMER\external\glfw-3.1.2\src\LINK  glfw
>
> Ошибка    3   error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "glu32.lib"  C:\Users\Виктор\Desktop\OPENGL_PRIMER\LINK  tutorial02_red_triangle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Случайно не [это](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ts7eyw4s.aspx) ищете?

Comment: Есть файлы lib борландовские, есть lib майкрософтовские, одни для продуктов borland другие для ms. Найдите в своём софте утилиту типа implib и импортируйте библиотеку, или скачайте другой lib файл, обратите внимание на фирму. Файлы отличаются заголовком конкретно, ну и структурой соответственно.

Comment: Укажите фирму имя вашего линкера/компилятора. Приветите heх-код c ascii-представлением справа ваших lib, что б было видно какой фирмы ваши lib. Скорее всего ваши lib не совместимы с вашим компилятором. Вам подскажут что делать зная какой у вас линкер.

Comment: @nick_n_a Выложил

Comment: Файл у вас microsoft. Компилятор какой? Если совет  PinkTux не помог, ищите lib для *вашего* компилятора.

Comment: Э... А к чему здесь экранный снимок HEX редактора с началом объектного файла `opengl32.lib`?

Answer (score 0):

Чем компилируете, с какими ключами? Вероятнее всего в путях поиска нет искомых файлов. Проверьте наличие файлов "opengl32.lib" и "glu32.lib" в системе. Если они у Вас расположены вне путей системной переменной %PATH%, то следует добавить в опции компилятора путь к папке библиотек:

-LC:\тут\лежат\lib-файлы\

Для Visual C++ так:  Project->Settings->LINK tab. В "Object/Library Modules" вначале строки добавить OpenGL32.lib GLu32.lib (и GLaux.lib).